# Import Kotlin class in Java Code - Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

I am working with an Android App written on Java and I need an external java file that imports some Kotlin Classes:

```
import kotlin.Pair;
import kotlin.Unit;
import kotlin.collections.CollectionsKt;
import kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1;
import kotlin.jvm.functions.Function2;
```

I just cannot find any information on how to edit my Gradle scripts that the compiler is able to resolve those classes. When trying to run I only get the error
`org.gradle.api.GradleException: Please initialize at least one Kotlin target in 'app (:app)'`

An instance of this class is created in my MainActivity.

My `build.gradle` for the Module contains the plugin `id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform' version '1.5.10'` and the dependencies

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.5.0'
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.5.10"
```

I am quite new to Gradle build scripts and I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

EDIT: I am using Gradle 7.0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your project-level `build.gradle`

```
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
```

And to the top of your app-level `build.gradle` file:

```
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
```

You may refer to [this](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/add-kotlin) in case you still face any issues.